# ListPlot3D weirdly distorts and loses plotting data

Tags: plotting, bugs, graphics3d

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.3.1 **

---

I was trying to plot a simple $n\times3$-sized $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ matrix data with `ListPlot3D`, which is basically three lines along $y$-direction. However, the middle part is completely lost and there seems other distortion as well. It doesn't occur when I check with `ListPlot` for each of the three lines.[image]

```
ListPlot3D[ha, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

And the data

```
ha = {{0.`, 0.`, 1.000000000000001`}, {0.`, 0.04220866428763286`, 
    1.000000000000001`}, {0.`, 0.16116035455278002`, 
    1.0000000000000013`}, {0.`, 0.3568550707954415`, 
    1.000000000000001`}, {0.`, 0.6292928130156172`, 
    1.000000000000001`}, {0.`, 0.9784735812133072`, 
    1.0000000000000009`}, {0.`, 1.4043973753885115`, 
    1.000000000000001`}, {0.`, 1.9070641955412304`, 
    1.000000000000001`}, {0.`, 2.486474041671463`, 
    1.000000000000001`}, {0.`, 3.1426269137792096`, 
    1.0000000000000009`}, {0.`, 3.8755228118644713`, 
    1.0000000000000007`}, {0.`, 4.685161735927248`, 
    1.0000000000000002`}, {0.`, 5.571543685967537`, 
    0.9999999999999999`}, {0.`, 6.534668661985342`, 
    0.9999999999999993`}, {0.`, 7.574536663980662`, 
    0.9999999999999986`}, {0.`, 8.691147691953493`, 
    0.9999999999999974`}, {0.`, 9.884501745903842`, 
    0.9999999999999963`}, {0.`, 11.154598825831703`, 
    0.9999999999999954`}, {0.`, 12.501438931737077`, 
    0.9999999999999949`}, {0.`, 13.925022063619968`, 
    0.9999999999999942`}, {0.`, 15.425348221480373`, 
    0.9999999999999936`}, {0.`, 17.002417405318294`, 
    0.9999999999999928`}, {0.`, 18.656229615133725`, 
    0.9999999999999922`}, {0.`, 20.386784850926674`, 
    0.9999999999999916`}, {0.`, 22.194083112697136`, 
    0.999999999999991`}, {0.`, 24.07812440044511`, 
    0.9999999999999905`}, {0.`, 26.038908714170606`, 
    0.99999999999999`}, {0.`, 28.076436053873604`, 
    0.9999999999999896`}, {0.`, 30.190706419554125`, 
    0.9999999999999892`}, {0.`, 32.381719811212164`, 
    0.999999999999989`}, {0.`, 34.6494762288477`, 
    0.9999999999999887`}, {0.`, 36.99397567246076`, 
    0.9999999999999886`}, {0.`, 39.41521814205134`, 
    0.9999999999999883`}, {0.`, 41.91320363761943`, 
    0.9999999999999883`}, {0.`, 44.48793215916504`, 
    0.9999999999999883`}, {0.`, 47.13940370668815`, 
    0.9999999999999883`}, {0.`, 49.86761828018879`, 
    0.9999999999999885`}, {0.`, 52.67257587966694`, 
    0.9999999999999885`}, {0.`, 55.55427650512259`, 
    0.9999999999999887`}, {0.`, 58.512720156555766`, 
    0.999999999999989`}, {0.`, 61.54790683396646`, 
    0.9999999999999892`}, {0.`, 64.65983653735468`, 
    0.9999999999999895`}, {0.`, 67.84850926672038`, 
    0.9999999999999897`}, {0.`, 71.11392502206361`, 
    0.9999999999999901`}, {0.`, 74.45608380338437`, 
    0.9999999999999905`}, {0.`, 77.87498561068263`, 
    0.9999999999999907`}, {0.`, 81.37063044395842`, 
    0.9999999999999932`}, {0.`, 84.94301830321169`, 
    0.9999999999999886`}, {0.`, 88.59214918844249`, 
    0.9999999999999765`}, {0.`, 92.31802309965083`, 
    1.0000000000004379`}, {0.`, 96.12064003683665`, 
    1.0000000000025797`}, {0.`, 100.`, 1.0000000000017453`}, {0.001`, 
    0.`, 0.9851456965785419`}, {0.001`, 0.04220866428763286`, 
    0.9807978862177816`}, {0.001`, 0.16116035455278002`, 
    0.9701113707294763`}, {0.001`, 0.3568550707954415`, 
    0.9551775783456566`}, {0.001`, 0.6292928130156172`, 
    0.938966241440333`}, {0.001`, 0.9784735812133072`, 
    0.9251572107453561`}, {0.001`, 1.4043973753885115`, 
    0.9164358919538024`}, {0.001`, 1.9070641955412304`, 
    0.9134215526191046`}, {0.001`, 2.486474041671463`, 
    0.9150120137733051`}, {0.001`, 3.1426269137792096`, 
    0.9194496552196791`}, {0.001`, 3.8755228118644713`, 
    0.9251679949629803`}, {0.001`, 4.685161735927248`, 
    0.9311110359028776`}, {0.001`, 5.571543685967537`, 
    0.9366974449748587`}, {0.001`, 6.534668661985342`, 
    0.9416642637206076`}, {0.001`, 7.574536663980662`, 
    0.9459077703484071`}, {0.001`, 8.691147691953493`, 
    0.9492727960322465`}, {0.001`, 9.884501745903842`, 
    0.9496894601285651`}, {0.001`, 11.154598825831703`, 
    0.9444346395454216`}, {0.001`, 12.501438931737077`, 
    0.9380124889601578`}, {0.001`, 13.925022063619968`, 
    0.930814905086062`}, {0.001`, 15.425348221480373`, 
    0.9227876161420403`}, {0.001`, 17.002417405318294`, 
    0.9138395812502855`}, {0.001`, 18.656229615133725`, 
    0.9038615966962887`}, {0.001`, 20.386784850926674`, 
    0.8927270336346949`}, {0.001`, 22.194083112697136`, 
    0.8802896371980299`}, {0.001`, 24.07812440044511`, 
    0.8663800048610383`}, {0.001`, 26.038908714170606`, 
    0.8508008043504566`}, {0.001`, 28.076436053873604`, 
    0.8333203705082056`}, {0.001`, 30.190706419554125`, 
    0.8136640055561997`}, {0.001`, 32.381719811212164`, 
    0.7915018693467315`}, {0.001`, 34.6494762288477`, 
    0.766431608818418`}, {0.001`, 36.99397567246076`, 
    0.7379525357279786`}, {0.001`, 39.41521814205134`, 
    0.7054255687489583`}, {0.001`, 41.91320363761943`, 
    0.668007778358783`}, {0.001`, 44.48793215916504`, 
    0.624538218099993`}, {0.001`, 47.13940370668815`, 
    0.5733210576487527`}, {0.001`, 49.86761828018879`, 
    0.5116622654510867`}, {0.001`, 52.67257587966694`, 
    0.4346902749397748`}, {0.001`, 55.55427650512259`, 
    0.33130339884032495`}, {0.001`, 58.512720156555766`, 
    0.15427506080560502`}, {0.001`, 61.54790683396646`, 
    2.5075562949280167`*^-11}, {0.001`, 64.65983653735468`, 
    2.5923992398533742`*^-20}, {0.001`, 67.84850926672038`, 
    3.0004356639293435`*^-13}, {0.001`, 71.11392502206361`, 
    4.399460615423633`*^-40}, {0.001`, 74.45608380338437`, 
    1.3035336686132412`*^-50}, {0.001`, 77.87498561068263`, 
    1.7915749403987287`*^-61}, {0.001`, 81.37063044395842`, 
    1.2546835829365311`*^-72}, {0.001`, 84.94301830321169`, 
    4.257926544060667`*^-15}, {0.001`, 88.59214918844249`, 
    1.0989735816206881`*^-95}, {0.001`, 92.31802309965083`, 
    5.372616958607281`*^-16}, {0.001`, 96.12064003683665`, 
    1.3462554804969502`*^-119}, {0.001`, 100.`, 
    9.396462133027396`*^-17}, {0.002`, 0.`, 
    0.9702854194086491`}, {0.002`, 0.04220866428763286`, 
    0.9615799650874828`}, {0.002`, 0.16116035455278002`, 
    0.9401603623570034`}, {0.002`, 0.3568550707954415`, 
    0.910139922530339`}, {0.002`, 0.6292928130156172`, 
    0.8773792041918361`}, {0.002`, 0.9784735812133072`, 
    0.8492795318523028`}, {0.002`, 1.4043973753885115`, 
    0.8314175647052442`}, {0.002`, 1.9070641955412304`, 
    0.8252191223825608`}, {0.002`, 2.486474041671463`, 
    0.8284882720732185`}, {0.002`, 3.1426269137792096`, 
    0.8375951953414753`}, {0.002`, 3.8755228118644713`, 
    0.8492937637750858`}, {0.002`, 4.685161735927248`, 
    0.8614112641110805`}, {0.002`, 5.571543685967537`, 
    0.8727670039728884`}, {0.002`, 6.534668661985342`, 
    0.8828376709411946`}, {0.002`, 7.574536663980662`, 
    0.8914244712269536`}, {0.002`, 8.691147691953493`, 
    0.8982243070632591`}, {0.002`, 9.884501745903842`, 
    0.8990833912251011`}, {0.002`, 11.154598825831703`, 
    0.8884740950975214`}, {0.002`, 12.501438931737077`, 
    0.8754686706446855`}, {0.002`, 13.925022063619968`, 
    0.8608453837805503`}, {0.002`, 15.425348221480373`, 
    0.8444696050275246`}, {0.002`, 17.002417405318294`, 
    0.8261211194573721`}, {0.002`, 18.656229615133725`, 
    0.8055266044958076`}, {0.002`, 20.386784850926674`, 
    0.7823531323815934`}, {0.002`, 22.194083112697136`, 
    0.7561911959487542`}, {0.002`, 24.07812440044511`, 
    0.7265273871355553`}, {0.002`, 26.038908714170606`, 
    0.6927009191720127`}, {0.002`, 28.076436053873604`, 
    0.6538313467191086`}, {0.002`, 30.190706419554125`, 
    0.6086901588358097`}, {0.002`, 32.381719811212164`, 
    0.5554510907737478`}, {0.002`, 34.6494762288477`, 
    0.49113879517423953`}, {0.002`, 36.99397567246076`, 
    0.41015049580923046`}, {0.002`, 39.41521814205134`, 
    0.29863294585807315`}, {0.002`, 41.91320363761943`, 
    0.061015753817889956`}, {0.002`, 44.48793215916504`, 
    6.734785731890138`*^-20}, {0.002`, 47.13940370668815`, 
    1.19665072428201`*^-12}, {0.002`, 49.86761828018879`, 
    6.834579450050555`*^-11}, {0.002`, 52.67257587966694`, 
    1.2923868774029326`*^-49}, {0.002`, 55.55427650512259`, 
    1.5623363881240579`*^-13}, {0.002`, 58.512720156555766`, 
    8.20616019091291`*^-72}, {0.002`, 61.54790683396646`, 
    1.9387838158153854`*^-83}, {0.002`, 64.65983653735468`, 
    1.776546358835029`*^-23}, {0.002`, 67.84850926672038`, 
    1.4018676559249928`*^-107}, {0.002`, 71.11392502206361`, 
    1.8702205077648395`*^-27}, {0.002`, 74.45608380338437`, 
    1.8814412334525443`*^-33}, {0.002`, 77.87498561068263`, 
    2.4699959562643973`*^-36}, {0.002`, 81.37063044395842`, 
    8.528212719579378`*^-159}, {0.002`, 84.94301830321169`, 
    4.0595031104357706`*^-172}, {0.002`, 88.59214918844249`, 
    1.2652311634065102`*^-185}, {0.002`, 92.31802309965083`, 
    2.63650817206882`*^-199}, {0.002`, 96.12064003683665`, 
    1.3352789152157276`*^-27}, {0.002`, 100.`, 
    2.0318155449586684`*^-29}};
```

Comment: Trying to rotate the figure causes my FrontEnd to hang...

Comment: it has to do to how some of your data are aligned I think. Try adding this option and see if it helps `MaxPlotPoints -> Length[ha]`

Comment: @Nasser With that option, It's still wrong and incomplete in a different way, as one can see from plotting each lines.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Weird... Not a large data set at all.

Comment: @xiaohuanmao, can you explain where these numbers are from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused by vastly different scales in x and y coordinates. We can replicate the issue by re-scaling one of the first two columns:

```
SeedRandom[1]
dt1 = Join @@ MapIndexed[Append[#2, #] &, RandomReal[1, {5, 10}], {2}];

dt2 = MapAt[10^-4 # &, dt1, {All, 1}]; 

Row[ListPlot3D[#, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {dt1, dt2}]
```

[image]

An easy fix is to (1) re-scale each column to the unit interval, (2) `ListPlot3D` the re-scaled data, and (3) post-process to undo the scaling:

```
ClearAll[reScale, scaleBack, undoScaling]

reScale = Transpose @* Map[Rescale] @* Transpose;

scaleBack = Transpose[MapThread[Rescale, 
   {Transpose[#], MinMax /@ Transpose[#], MinMax /@ Transpose[#2]}]] &;

undoScaling[x_] := # /. GraphicsComplex[a_, b__] :> GraphicsComplex[scaleBack[a, x], b]&

lp3D = undoScaling[ha] @ ListPlot3D[reScale @ ha, Mesh -> All];

Show[ListPointPlot3D[ha], lp3D, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Not certain what is going on but you can work around with [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html).

```
ifoo = Interpolation[ha, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[ha, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  ImageSize -> Large],
 Plot3D[ifoo[x, y], 
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ MapThread[Prepend, {ifoo["Domain"], {x, y}}]], 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

You should send your example to Wolfram Support as I think it should work with the [`InterpolationOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html) option of [`ListPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html) but that does not appear to change the plot. Would like to know what they come up with.

Hope this helps.