# problem with ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I have problem with   `ListDensityPlot[data,PlotRange -> All]`.

[image]

```
data = {{-1.25, -5000., 22.7941}, {-1.25, -4800., 21.8831}, {-1.25, -4600., 20.9713}, {-1.25, -4400., 20.0591}, {-1.25, -4200., 19.1478}, {-1.25, -4000., 18.2354}, {-1.25, -3800., 17.3227}, {-1.25, -3600., 16.4117}, {-1.25, -3400., 15.5004}, {-1.25, -3200., 14.5881}, {-1.25, -3000., 13.6769}, {-1.2, -5000., 22.7941}, {-1.2, -4800., 21.8817}, {-1.2, -4600., 20.9713}, {-1.2, -4400., 20.0591}, {-1.2, -4200., 19.1466}, {-1.2, -4000., 18.2349}, {-1.2, -3800., 17.3227}, {-1.2, -3600., 16.4123}, {-1.2, -3400., 15.5004}, {-1.2, -3200., 14.5881}, {-1.2, -3000., 13.677}, {-1.15, -5000., 22.7941}, {-1.15, -4800., 21.8831}, {-1.15, -4600., 20.97}, {-1.15, -4400., 20.0591}, {-1.15, -4200., 19.1466}, {-1.15, -4000., 18.2354}, {-1.15, -3800., 17.3227}, {-1.15, -3600., 16.4123}, {-1.15, -3400., 15.4995}, {-1.15, -3200., 14.5881}, {-1.15, -3000., 13.6762}, {-1.1, -5000., 22.7941}, {-1.1, -4800., 21.8831}, {-1.1, -4600., 20.97}, {-1.1, -4400., 20.0591}, {-1.1, -4200., 19.1465}, {-1.1, -4000., 18.2354}, {-1.1, -3800., 17.3227}, {-1.1, -3600., 16.4117}, {-1.1, -3400., 15.4995}, {-1.1, -3200., 14.5881}, {-1.1, -3000., 13.6762}, {-1.05, -5000., 22.7941}, {-1.05, -4800., 21.8817}, {-1.05, -4600., 20.97}, {-1.05, -4400., 20.0579}, {-1.05, -4200., 19.1465}, {-1.05, -4000., 18.2342}, {-1.05, -3800.,  17.3227}, {-1.05, -3600., 16.4117}, {-1.05, -3400., 15.5004}, {-1.05, -3200., 14.5881}, {-1.05, -3000., 13.677}}
```

At the edge of the image I see those teeth, but the data shows no discontinuity and looks similar to the core data. I would expect the graph to be continuous. Why is this?

Comment: Try `InterpolationOrder -> 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by vastly different scales for the vertical and horizontal axes.

Two work-arounds:

**1.** Use the option [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html):

```
{xrange, yrange} = MinMax /@ Transpose[data][[;; 2]];

ListDensityPlot[data, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", 
   {Rescale[#, yrange, xrange] &, Rescale[#, xrange, yrange] &}}]
```

[image]

**2.** Rescale the first and second columns of input data and use custom frame-ticks:

```
data2 = Transpose[{Rescale@#, Rescale@#2, #3} & @@ Transpose[data]];

fticks = {Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, #], Automatic} & /@ {yrange, xrange};

ListDensityPlot[data2, PlotRange -> All, FrameTicks -> fticks]
```

[image]

**Related Q/As:**

1. [ListDensityPlot    problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219578/125)
2. [ListPlot3D weirdly distorts and loses plotting data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/214453/125)