# Why doesn't the 'If' statement work in Mathematica 12 for plotting?

Tags: plotting

I have the following code:

```
Subscript[a, 0] = 3.88/10^14; 
G = 6.67384/10^20; 
solarMass = 1.9891*10^30; 
massFunction[velocity_, radius_] := If[velocity^2 < Subscript[a, 0]*radius, 0, ((velocity^2 - Subscript[a, 0]*radius)*radius)/(G*solarMass)]; 
fundamentalPlane = Plot3D[massFunction[v, r], {v, 50, 700}, {r, 0, 1*10^19}, AxesLabel -> {Style["velocity", FontSize -> 14], Style["radius", FontSize -> 14], Null}, ImageSize -> Large]; 
maximumMass = Graphics3D[Point[Table[{v, v^2/(2*Subscript[a, 0]), 49*v^4}, {v, 50, 700}]]]; 
Show[fundamentalPlane, maximumMass]
```

In Mathematica 10.3, it produced this graph:

[image]

In Mathematica 12, it produces this graph (I haven't changed the code):

[image]

The problem appears to be the 'If' statement.  I'm using the conditional function to crop out values that are not physical (such as negative mass).  What am I doing wrong and is there a better, more supportable way of removing values from a 3D plot that are not part of the solution domain?

Comment: In 12.1 Windows10, simply adding `PlotPoints->10` causes _Mathematica_ to hang. It does complete though with an undesirable result.

Comment: It's not specific to the`If` statement - you can replace it with a `UnitStep` and product but it's still bad: `UnitStep[velocity^2 - Subscript[a,0]*radius]*((velocity^2 - Subscript[a,0]*radius)*radius)/(G*solarMass)`

Comment: You can use `PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}` if you want to crop out negative values and this looks much better. But still it doesn't explain the regression in `Plot3D` behaviour. There's nothing wrong  with your code in my opinion, as this looks correct: `ListPointPlot3D[Flatten[Table[{v, r, massFunction[v, r]}, {v, 50, 700, 10}, {r, 0, 1*10^19, 10^17}], 1]]` so I'm guessing `Plot3D` changed how it handled large plot ranges in v11 or 12.

Comment: @flinty - The PlotRange appears to have done the trick.  I don't know if there's a more elegant way of doing this using domains, but if you'd like to post this as an answer, I'll up-vote it.

Comment: I think an answer should also explain why the `Plot3D` plot range behaviour has changed and I don't know this. I'd prefer if somebody with deeper knowledge would answer it.

Comment: seems to be related: [ListPlot3D weirdly distorts and loses plotting data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/214453/125) and [Problem with ListDensityPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/221019/125)

Comment: I don't know if I'd call this a bug, but it is at least a [tag:backslide].  I'd consider reporting it to WRI support.  They might be able to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify `Exclusions -> None`:

```
Plot3D[massFunction[v, r], {v, 50, 700}, {r, 0, 1*10^19}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["velocity", FontSize -> 14], 
   Style["radius", FontSize -> 14], Null}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Exclusion processing has been made more robust over time.  It seems overeager in this case.