ListDensityPlot plots data incorrectly near function's peak, Data Range changes plotted distribution
I cannot understand the issue I faced with the plot when using ListDensityPlot. I have equidistant points in x coordinate ('LengRange'), and nonequidistand along y-axis (Rr), and calculate function Xi of these coordinates as a Table (XiList0). Next, I join coordinates and functions in the stack as $\{Leng_i,Rr_i,Xi_i\}$ and try to plot them with ListDensityPlot. However what I found is that the ListDensityPlot does not represent the data as expected.
At the end, I want to obtain the following (with the axes scaled in the range {{0,2},{1,250}}):

However when I try to achieve the desired result I got completely confused with what I get:

plot XiList0 distribution only. Distribution is correct but ticks labels are wrong.
plot $\{Leng_i,Rr_i,Xi_i\}$ set. The distribution is not properly drawn (InterpolationOrder->0, does not help)
Deciding that the problem might be of inapropriate accuracy for drawing, i increased y-coordinate 10 times (10  LengRange[[a1]]), see Coords2, resultant distribution is different from the desired one on the first fig.
Finally I added DataRange to change scales to my need, and the distribution id totally different to what I wanted, and what is most impotrant the slices along y-axis are equidastant what ais wrong according to the defined list Rr.

Community, need your help to get desired plot at the image above.
The code:
LengRange=Subdivide[0.9,1.1,1000];
Rr={1,10,20,50,100,120,150,160,170,190, 200,210,230,250 };
Xi=(6*^13/Abs[6*^13-((0.024 I) (1+2120/(4.6*^7/R+8000) ) Leng)/(6840 R)-6*^13 Leng^2]);
XiList0=Table[Log10[Xi]/.R->10^-9 Rr[[kk]],{kk,Range[14]},{Leng,LengRange}];
XiList=Partition[Flatten[XiList0,1],1];
---
Coords1=Flatten[Table[{LengRange[[a1]],Rr[[b1]]},{b1,1,14,1},{a1,1,1001,1}],1];
Coords2=Flatten[Table[{10  LengRange[[a1]],Rr[[b1]]},{b1,1,14,1},{a1,1,1001,1}],1];
---
List1=Join[Coords1,XiList,2];
List2=Join[Coords2,XiList,2];
---
{ListDensityPlot[XiList0,PlotRange->All],ListDensityPlot[List1,PlotRange->All],ListDensityPlot[List2,PlotRange->All],ListDensityPlot[List2,PlotRange->All,DataRange->{{0,2},{1,250}}]}

Output:


The labels MMA draws are ok, you did not specify that you want other labels and coordinates. For this you have to specify: {x,y,f[x,y]} like:
d = Table[{2 (i - 1)/(Length[XiList0[[1]]] - 1), 
    250 (j - 1)/(Length[XiList0] - 1), XiList0[[j, i]]}, {i, 
    Length[XiList0[[1]]]}, {j, Length[XiList0]}];
ListDensityPlot[Flatten[d, 1]]



Thank you. Any ideas how to fix artifacts on the very right edge? I have checked it is not the matter of the PlotRange.

I do not know the reason for this bug, but you may eliminate it by: PlotRange -> {{0, 1.95}, {0, 250}}

In fact this proposal does not work once one add PlotRange->All to ListDensityPlot

Of course you can not specify both.

Thanks to the respond: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/219584/92499, the point is:

When x and y coordinates have vastly different scales, plot functions
can give unexpected results

Well the ScalingFunctions is the solution.
A code satisfying my needs is:
ListDensityPlot[List1, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {{# 10^3 &, # 10^-3 &}, "Linear"}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {{{0.9, 0}, {0.95, 0.5}, {1, 1}, {1.05, 1.5}, {1.1, 2}}, None}}]


