# Unwanted clipped regions in ListContourPlot, ListDensityPlot, or ListPlot3D on Windows

Tags: plotting, bugs, interpolation, windows

Let my data be something like

```
dat = {{{-2., -0.00046, 371.312}, {-2., -0.000368, 370.61}, {-2., -0.000276,
    369.839}, {-2., -0.000184, 368.733}, {-2., -0.000092, 
   366.91}, {-2., 0., 362.287}}, {{-1.6, -0.00046, 
   370.465}, {-1.6, -0.000368, 369.869}, {-1.6, -0.000276, 
   369.083}, {-1.6, -0.000184, 367.894}, {-1.6, -0.000092, 
   366.075}, {-1.6, 0., 361.47}}, {{-1.2, -0.00046, 
   369.414}, {-1.2, -0.000368, 369.009}, {-1.2, -0.000276, 
   368.119}, {-1.2, -0.000184, 367.123}, {-1.2, -0.000092, 
   365.225}, {-1.2, 0., 360.638}}, {{-0.8, -0.00046, 
   368.53}, {-0.8, -0.000368, 367.945}, {-0.8, -0.000276, 
   367.358}, {-0.8, -0.000184, 366.255}, {-0.8, -0.000092, 
   364.358}, {-0.8, 0., 359.79}}, {{-0.4, -0.00046, 
   367.629}, {-0.4, -0.000368, 367.046}, {-0.4, -0.000276, 
   366.466}, {-0.4, -0.000184, 365.258}, {-0.4, -0.000092, 
   363.474}, {-0.4, 0., 358.926}}, {{0., -0.00046, 
   366.71}, {0., -0.000368, 366.13}, {0., -0.000276, 
   365.366}, {0., -0.000184, 364.35}, {0., -0.000092, 362.573}, {0., 
   0., 358.045}}}
```

And then we plot with:

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten[datP2A2, 1], PlotRange -> All]
```

yields

[image]

or

```
ListContourPlot[Flatten[datP1A1,1],Contours->12,PlotRange->All]
```

gives

[image]

Note that I am using PlotRange->All as the only suggestions have been given. I should also note that this does not occur on Linux! The full smooth data range is given in Linux no problem. I am using Windows 10 and Mathematica 12.2. Does anyone know what is going on? something to do with automatic clipping?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by vastly different scales in x and y coordinates as [in this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/214453/125). As a work-around we can use the rescaling approach from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/215906/125):

```
ClearAll[reScale, scaleBack, undoScaling]

reScale = Transpose @* Map[Rescale] @* Transpose;

scaleBack = Transpose[MapThread[Rescale, 
   {Transpose[#], MinMax /@ Transpose[#], MinMax /@ Transpose[#2]}]] &;

undoScaling[x_] := Show[# /. 
    GraphicsComplex[a_, b__] :> GraphicsComplex[scaleBack[a, x], b], PlotRange -> All] &

data = Flatten[dat, 1];

undoScaling[data] @ ListPlot3D[reScale @ data]
```

[image]

```
undoScaling[data[[All, ;; 2]]] @ ListContourPlot[reScale @ data, Contours -> 12]
```

[image]