# Artifacts when interpolating on an unstructured set of 3D data

Tags: graphics3d, finite-element-method, interpolation

When doing an interpolation on an unstructured set of points it is best to use the interpolation method available from the finite element package. However, it is essential that some re-scaling is done so that a good mesh can be achieved. I have hit this problem before and this is a continuation of the problem I discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/235681/12558).

I now have the problem of reversing the scaling so that I can have an interpolation function in the  true values. I can do this but artifacts appear on the boundary due to unwanted extrapolation. Can these be avoided or at least removed?

I start by making some points and values to go with the points

```
pts = Table[t {100 Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 100, 0.1}];
values = {#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[1]] #[[2]]^2} & /@ pts;
pa = Graphics3D[Point[values], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Note that the scaling on the x and y axes differ by a factor of 100.

The next step is to re-scale make the mesh and an interpolation function on the mesh. This works as follows

```
        Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
{x1, x2} = MinMax[pts[[All, 1]]];
{y1, y2} = MinMax[pts[[All, 2]]];
pts1 = {Rescale[#[[1]], {x1, x2}, {-1, 1}], 
     Rescale[#[[2]], {y1, y2}, {-1, 1}]} & /@ pts;
mesh = ToElementMesh[pts1];
int = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, values[[All, 3]],
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Function[Indeterminate], 
     "WarningMessage" -> False}];
Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

This is all very satisfactory but my axes are scaled between -1 to 1.
To un-scale I have made a function that maps the un-scaled data to the scaled data. This works but on plotting there are artifacts on the boundary.

```
ClearAll[fint];
fint[x_, y_] := 
  int[-1 + 2 (x - x1)/(x2 - x1), -1 + 2 (y - y1)/(y2 - y1)];
Plot3D[fint[x, y], {x, -10000, 10000}, {y, -100, 100}, 
 PlotPoints -> {100, 100},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Can the artifacts be removed? Perhaps I am being too fussy but I am also concerned that if I use the interpolation function then I could get false outputs.

**Edit**

Henrik Schumacher asks "Why do you rescale at all?

If we don't rescale then this is the mesh we get

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[pts];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

This is clearly hopeless and I think it may be the reason why `ListPlot3D` does not work. Thus

```
ListPlot3D[values, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you rescale at all? Apparently, the rescaling leads to tiny errors for the boundary points so that some of them fall outside of the domain of interpolant.

Comment: Could you use the mesh as a plot range?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  Please see edit which shows why it does not work

Comment: @user21 Could you explain more? For an irregular region I can't see how to use `PlotRange`

Comment: @Hugh Uh, oh. Thank you for the plot. Now I realize that object has very different size in the x- and y-direction (which makes problems with the mesh generation).

Comment: try `undoScaling[values] @ ListPlot3D[reScale @ values]` using the functions `undoScaling` and `reScale`  from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/215906/125) ?

Comment: see also [this related Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/253497/125)

Comment: I mean: `Plot3D[..., Element[{x, y}, mesh]`

Comment: Another thing to try is to use an Automatic extrapolation handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
m1 = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> pts];
ClearAll[fint];
fint[x_, y_] := 
  int[-1 + 2 (x - x1)/(x2 - x1), -1 + 2 (y - y1)/(y2 - y1)];
Plot3D[fint[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] m1, PlotPoints -> {100, 100}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: A good and surprising answer. It seems that although you are using the bad mesh I show in the question this mesh works well as a definition of the region to be plotted.

Comment: The solution from @kglr unscales the data in the plot. Is it possible to unscale  the coordinates in the mesh?

Comment: @Hugh, not that I can think of now.