# One problem with ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, image3d, webmathematica

I plot a table in Mathematica using ListPlot3D. The table contains very simple data but the resulting plot is very weird at least for me. I expect that the plot should look like a rectangle in 3D but there is a jump in the plot. Could you please help me to figure out what is the problem? Here is the information about the table and the plot picture.

Let

```
wpb1New = Table[{1/10000 + i/100000}, {i, 0, 90}];
```

and

```
wb1New = Table[{1 + i/100}, {i, 0, 200}];
```

Then the ListPlot3D of the following table looks like

```
TItest = Flatten[Table[{wb1New[[i]], wpb1New[[j]], wpb1New[[j]]}, {i, 1, 201}, {j, 1, 91}], 1];
```

[image]

Comment: `ListPlot3D[TItest]` gives an error on Mathematica v12.2

Comment: To start, re-define `wpb1New` and `wb1New` without braces in the `Table`: that will give you a more reasonable list structure for `TItest`. That does not solve the problem you mention though.

Comment: This is caused by a bug (wierd clippings occur when the axes have _very_ different scales). Try this: (1) Remove braces in the first argument of `Table` in definitions of `wpb1New` and `wb1New` as MarcoB suggested in comments; (2) Use `undoScaling[TItest]@ListPlot3D[reScale@TItest]`  where the functions `reScale` and `undoScaling` are from  [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/215906/125) .

Comment: The code should be `wpb1New = Table[1/10000 + i/100000, {i, 0, 90}];
wb1New = Table[1 + i/100, {i, 0, 200}];`

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @kglr Thanks a lot! That fixed the problem.

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you for your comment!